# How to run JFileChooser Swing component in OpenBravo ERP?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, erp, openbravo

I am new to OpenBravo ERP development. I have developed module in Openbravo ERP and want to add feature of choosing file from the user using `JFileChooser`. But no success!

Can you help me out?  How to run file chooser Swing component in OpenBravo ERP?

Comment: Your question to too broad right, now. What have you tried specifically, and what problems have you had with that?

Comment: *"But no success!!"*  What did you try?  Show us in the form of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  How did it fail?  *"Can u help me out?"*  You can help yourself out by spelling words like 'you' correctly.  These are not SMS messages we are sending back and forth, we have access to full-size keyboards and should use them to type full words.

Comment: *"Openbravo ERP is the **web-based** ERP (Enterprise Resource Planning) solution for SMB."*  Oh, if you mean open a file chooser for the **end user,** that would mean creating a (trusted) applet.  Down that path lies madness.  Use the browser based file chooser.